# Haskell wai middleware - how to run application if 404 is returned from the first application?

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai

I'm trying to 'join' two wai `Application`s together. Essentially the first app will either serve a **404 Not found response** or a response that is not a **404 Not found response**. I'd like to add a second application that will attempt to process the request if the first case (first application returns a **404**) is present.

However looking at the type of `Application`:

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

It's not clear how to inspect the response? As wouldn't I just end up with `ResponseRecived` as the end result - which does not seem to contain any response code. As seen below:

```
xyzMiddle :: (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived) ->
             (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived)
xyzMiddle app req respond = do
  zzz <- (app req respond)
  pure zzz
```

How could I implement this? And or, what am I failing to understand in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked this `(Response -> IO ResponseReceived)` as that is in the `IO` context - this is where we can run the second application. Which means, to inspect the `Response` we can do something like:

```
xyzMiddle :: (Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived) ->
             Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
xyzMiddle app req respond = app req (\r -> do
  print $ show $ responseStatus r
  respond r)
```